# What are the exact abilities of the Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

Like my question is asking, what are the exact abilities of the Rinnegan?

I only know that Rinnegan users can bring the dead back to life, absorb chakra, extracted people's souls while also reading their minds, summon people and animals, and sharing vision with the Six Paths of Pain.

Of course I know there are more abilities the Rinnegan grants, but I don't know them. Would you please answer with as much detail as possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The Rinnegan grants the wielder a wide range of abilities without any known chakra requirement to keep the eyes active.

**Although some abilities are only available to the original owner of the Rinnegan, even the possession of one can grant overwhelming power.**

- The Rinnegan can see chakra, as well as its flow within the body and the activated tenketsu of the Eight Gates, but cannot see through smoke bombs.
- A Rinnegan user can easily master any jutsu and all five nature transformations
- Create black receivers in which they can transmit their chakra
- Fully decipher the stone tablet
- Counter the effects of the Infinite Tsukuyomi.

Possessing the Rinnegan grants the user abilities known as the Six Paths Techniques (despite the name, there’s actually seven paths): Deva Path, Asura Path, Human Path, Animal Path, Preta Path, Naraka Path, and the Outer Path.

> - [Deva Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Deva_Path): grants the user the ability to manipulate attractive and repulsive forces with objects and people
> - [Asura Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Asura_Path): grants the user the ability to augment their own body to summon mechanised armour and various ballistic and mechanical weaponry.
> - [Human Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Path): grants the user the ability to read the mind of any target by placing his/her hand on the target's head or chest and yanking the soul out of the body, which then kills the target.
> - [Animal Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Path): grants the user the ability of summoning various animals and creatures which requires no blood sacrifice nor hand seals. The Animal Path can also summon people which require hand signs.
> - [Preta Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Preta_Path): grants the user the ability to absorb chakra in any form, including most ninjutsu, using the Blocking Technique Absorption Seal.
> - [Naraka Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naraka_Path): grants the user two main abilities: interrogation and restoration, by using the King of Hell.
> - [Outer Path](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path): grants the user the ability to revive the dead, transmit chakra to receivers, as well as manifest chakra chains, which can be used to blind tailed beasts.

The Paths mentioned above, not counting the Outer Path, can be distributed to the Six Paths of Pain — six bodies embedded with black receivers, which the user can control.

- The user can also summon and control the Gedo Statue
- The user is also granted a shared field of vision with the Six Paths of Pain, the King of Hell, and the Animal Path's summons, which possess copies of the Rinnegan.

Some Rinnegan users like Madara, Sasuke, and Momoshiki have some abilities others don’t.

> - Madara can create corporeal shadows in the invisible world of Limbo, which is only visible to the Rinnegan
> - Sasuke's Rinnegan allows him to shift spaces within a certain range of himself, and create portals to other dimensions
> - Momoshiki is able to absorb any ninjutsu with his right Rinnegan and subsequently release it from his left, transform others into chakra-filled edibles, and use a space–time ninjutsu to travel to and from a separate dimension.

Sources:

- [Rinnegan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan)

Answer (score 0):

With the Rinnegan you can also summon the Juubi (Ten Tails). Chakra rods can be used to transmit the signals, and can disturb the chakra flow when inserted. Whereas Sasuke, with his advanced Rinnegan with Sharingan, can teleport himself to an object in sight.